# Double enhanced for loop to count in a boolean[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, return, boolean

I'm supposed make a method with a return value that counts the number of false values in a 2d boolean array (seating arrangement in a cinema) using a double enhanced for loop. The program won't run due to issues with the return statement.

Here is my code:

```
public static byte emptySeats(boolean[][] cinemaSeats) {
    int availableSeats = 0;
    int rowLength = cinemaSeats.length;
    int seatLength = cinemaSeats[0].length;

    for (boolean[] radNr : cinemaSeats) {
        rowLength--;
        for (boolean[] seteNr : cinemaSeats) {
            seatLength--;
            if (!cinemaSeats[rowLength][seatLength]) {
                availableSeats++;
            }
        }
    }
    return availableSeats;
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a `byte`? Why not an `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enhanced for loop for 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931332/enhanced-for-loop-for-2d-array-in-java)

Comment: Integer is the appropriate to be returned if the goal is to count.

Answer (score 2):

This will iterate through each element in the array, searching for false values and adding to the total accordingly:

```
public static int emptySeats(boolean[][] cinemaSeats) {
    int availableSeats = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < cinemaSeats.length; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < cinemaSeats[y].length; x++)
            if (!cinemaSeats[y][x]) availableSeats++;
    return availableSeats;
}
```

Here's a similar solution using enhanced for loops:

```
public static int emptySeats(boolean[][] cinemaSeats) {
    int availableSeats = 0;
    for (boolean[] row : cinemaSeats)
        for (boolean seat : row)
            if (!seat) availableSeats++;
    return availableSeats;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are using enhanced for loop and also creating 2 variable for
>   index. its not the right way. below is proper code for enhanced for
>   loop.
>
> Also you are returning integer and your method return type is byte.

```
public static int emptySeats (boolean [][] cinemaSeats) {

int availableSeats = 0;

        for (boolean[] radNr : cinemaSeats) {
            for(boolean seteNr : radNr) {
                if(!seteNr){
                availableSeats++;
                }
            }
        }
return availableSeats;
}
```